# Como creo una pagina extra de post en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quiero mantener mi pagina de post pero agregar una nueva seccion de post que se llama destinos, adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba de preguntar en https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas, ¿quieres crear un nuevo tipo de post o sea un custom post type? ¿Quieres crear un post con una plantilla personalizada?

Comment: Hola, ya resolvi, soy nuevo en wordpress por eso no me pude explicar pero encontre la respuesta en esta URL https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/creacion-custom-post-type-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según te entiendo necesitas crear un Custom Post Type.

Para hacerlo puedes pegar esto en tu archivo functions.php de tu plantilla. 
Si necesitas saber como mejorar este custom type puedes consultar el codex de wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

function create_posttype() {

```
register_post_type( 'destinos',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Destinos' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Destino' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'destinos'),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```